# Why is the sign different after subtracting unsigned and signed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, unsigned, negative-number

```
unsigned int t = 10;
int d = 16;
float c = t - d;
int e = t - d;
```

Why is the value of `c` positive but `e` negative?

Comment: Most compilers have an option to warn you if you're implicitly converting a `signed` value to `unsigned` or vice versa. On GCC and Clang, this is `-Wconversion`. Your question is a good example of why it's a good idea to compile with that.

Comment: it would help if you show the actual values you see.

Answer (score 65):

Let's start by analysing the result of `t - d`.

`t` is an `unsigned int` while `d` is an `int`, so to do arithmetic on them, the value of `d` is converted to an `unsigned int` (C++ rules say unsigned gets preference here). So we get `10u - 16u`, which (assuming 32-bit `int`) wraps around to `4294967290u`.

This value is then converted to `float` in the first declaration, and to `int` in the second one.

Assuming the typical implementation of `float` (32-bit single-precision IEEE), its highest representable value is roughly `1e38`, so `4294967290u` is well within that range. There will be rounding errors, but the conversion to float won't overflow.

For `int`, the situation's different. `4294967290u` is too big to fit into an `int`, so wrap-around happens and we arrive back at the value `-6`. Note that such wrap-around is not guaranteed by the standard: the resulting value in this case is implementation-defined<sup>(1)</sup>, which means it's up to the compiler what the result value is, but it must be documented.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> C++17 (N4659), [conv.integral] 7.8/3:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type;
>   otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

Comment: Just curious, but does in this case *implementation-defined* means hardware related? Since, most common hardware is two's-complement, you got this behavior, but it would change on a ones-complement CPU even using the same compiler?

Comment: @user1810087 It means that the compiler must document what will happen, which means the compiler authors must think about what will happen, and implement it consistently (or at least document it consistently with implementation). It's quite likely their decision will be influenced by the target HW, and so the documentation of this will be platform-specific.

Comment: It's not _behavior_ which is implementation-defined — only value (see your own footnote). In particular, implementation can't throw an exception, raise a signal etc. due to such conversion.

Answer (score 15):

First, you have to understand ["usual arithmetic conversions"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) (that link is for C, but the rules are the same in C++). In C++, if you do arithmetic with mixed types (you should avoid that when possible, by the way), there's a set of rules that decides which type the calculation is done in.

In your case, you are subtracting a signed int from an unsigned int. The promotion rules say that the actual calculation is done using `unsigned int`.

So your calculation is `10 - 16` in unsigned int arithmetic. Unsigned arithmetic is modulo arithmetic, meaning that it wraps around. So, assuming your typical 32-bit int, the result of this calculation is 2^32 - 6.

This is the same for both lines. Note that the subtraction is completely independent from the assignment; the type on the left side has absolutely no influence on how the calculation happens. It is a common beginner mistake to think that the type on the left side somehow influences the calculation; but `float f = 5 / 6` is zero, because the division still uses integer arithmetic.

The difference, then, is what happens during the assignment. The result of the subtraction is implicitly converted to `float` in one case, and `int` in the other.

The conversion to float tries to find the closest value to the actual one that the type can represent. This will be some very large value; not quite the one the original subtraction yielded though.

The conversion to int says that if the value fits into the range of int, the value will be unchanged. But 2^32 - 6 is far larger than the 2^31 - 1 that a 32-bit int can hold, so you get the other part of the conversion rule, which says that the resulting value is implementation-defined. This is a term in the standard that means "different compilers can do different things, but they have to document what they do".

For all practical purposes, all compilers that you'll likely encounter say that the bit pattern stays the same and is just interpreted as signed. Because of the way 2's complement arithmetic works (the way that almost all computers represent negative numbers), the result is the -6 you would expect from the calculation.

But all this is a very long way of repeating the first point, which is "don't do mixed type arithmetic". Cast the types first, explicitly, to types that you know will do the right thing.

Comment: I think you meant `2^31-1` for your second value in paragraph 7. Because "2^32 - 6 is far larger than the 2^32 - 1" doesn't, on the face of it, seem an obvious thing to assert. Most people would think that the first was exactly 5 less than the second, not far larger :-)